# Adding a bingmap on a html webpage javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps, bing-api

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetMap()
{ 

  var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), 
   {credentials: "Your Bing Maps Key",
   center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5),
   mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
    zoom: 7});
 }
 </script>
 </head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
 <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>  
</body>
  </html>
```

I've tried even loading a simlple map but I get a js error on the Microsoft class undefined

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to the <head> section of your page, before the section that you've pasted above:

```
<script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript"
charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the include for the maps api?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bingmaps.js"></script>
```

Or are you using the rest service, in which case you need to specify the location of the service in an AJAX call...

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/10/using-jquery-with-the-bing-maps-rest-api/